# Adding int to arraylist only if it does not already exist

Tags: android, arraylist

I have `position` that is equal to which question is shown. I want to add an int equal to `position` to an arraylist. Then I want to check and see if that arraylist has that int within it to prevent that int being added again. With the following code it adds the `position` int multiple times.

```
if(correctQuestions.size() == 0){
        correctQuestions.add(position);
    }else if(correctQuestions.size() > 0){
        if(!Arrays.asList(correctQuestions).contains(position)){
            correctQuestions.add(position);
        }
    }
```

If `position = 0;` then each run of this code will continually add `position` to my arraylist regardless if 0 is in it or not. For instance running this code 3 times will result in my arraylist outputting [0,0,0] when it should only allow it to add 0 once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must write like this:

```
if(correctQuestions.size() == 0){
    correctQuestions.add(position);
}else if(correctQuestions.size() > 0){
    if(!correctQuestions.contains(position)){
        correctQuestions.add(position);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
if(correctQuestions.indexOf(position) < 0) {//this will return -1 if object not found in the arraylist
    correctQuestions.add(position);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have maximum index of your Arraylist assume it as variable **size**.
So you can write conditional logic :

```
if(size!=0 && position < size ){
    correctQuestions.add(position);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method arrayList.size() returns the number of items in the list - so if the index is greater than or equal to the size(), it doesn't exist.

```
if(correctQuestions.size() > position){

        correctQuestions.add(position);

}

if you want to check if position already present in arraylist if `correctQuestions.get( index );` in try block shows that if no key present it will throw in catch

try {
    correctQuestions.get( index );
} catch ( IndexOutOfBoundsException e ) {
    correctQuestions.add( index, new Object() );
}
```